# Invalid floating point comparison in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, comparison

I have a weird dilema that I can't seem to place a finger on the issue and would like some outside assistance when trying to figure out the issue. I have a NSString value that I read in from a textbox and I convert it into a NSNumber. This works well and I get my value. Then I take my new number and I want to compare it with an array of 4 floating point numbers. However, when I try to compare I never get the proper results and this is where I am pulling my hair out. Below is a small snippet of code explaining my situation:

```
// THE FIRST IF STATEMENT IS WHAT GETS SELECTED
// newValue = 0.93
// colorRange = {0.10, 0.20, 0.80, 0.90 }
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *newValue = [format numberFromString:value];
[format release];

if (newValue < [colorRange objectAtIndex:0]) {
    // Red background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if (newValue > [colorRange objectAtIndex:0] && newValue < [colorRange objectAtIndex:1]) {
    // White background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else if (newValue > [colorRange objectAtIndex:1] && newValue < [colorRange objectAtIndex:2]) {
    // Black background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
else if (newValue > [colorRange objectAtIndex:2] && newValue < [colorRange objectAtIndex:3]) {
    // Blue background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else {
    // Green background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

What I am trying to do is see where my input value lies within my percentage range and select a color based on that information. If there is a more optimal way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: You have got a number of good answers already explaining that you do a comparison with a pointer address. However, even if you did everything right there still is a minor flaw in your algorithm. You are using greater than and less than only. Some of these should include the equal sign. Otherwise the values of 0.10, 0.20, 0.80 and 0.90 will always result in greenColors for the background because none of the conditions will return true and greenColors is the final else branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not compare NSNumbers directly like that, as you are comparing the values of their pointers.  Instead, use the `compare` method of NSNumber to compare them like this:

```
if ([newValue compare:[colorRange objectAtIndex:0]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // Red background
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}  
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in simple way:

```
if ([newValue floatVaue] < [colorRange objectAtIndex:0] floatValue])
```

And it is.

Comment: You'd need to add `[... floatVaue] to the right-hand side as well.

Comment: Thanks for hint! Didn't knew thats also NSNumber

Comment: And while you could do this, since they are both NSNumbers, why would you want to convert both of them to floats and then compare them? ;)

Comment: Given `colorRange = {0.10, 0.20, 0.80, 0.90 }` it is an array of scalar floats (double I suppose) and not NSNumber Objects. In that case you better don't add floatValue on the right hand side. Whether that is good style or not.

Comment: Well, we were also given `newValue = 0.93` and told that it was an NSNumber object, so I believe that the comments were simply to let us know what the values are.

Answer (score 3):

This (and the others like it):

```
newValue < [colorRange objectAtIndex:1]
```

Compares the pointer `newValue` to the pointer `[colorRange objectAtIndex:1]`. So it'll evaluate to non-zero if `newValue` happens to be lower down in memory.

Having been beaten to saying that by at least two posters, I'll take the time to propose the more compact method:

```
NSArray *backgroundColours = @[ [UIColor redColor], [UIColor whiteColor], ...];
NSUInteger index = 0;
for(NSNumber *colour in colorRange)
{
    if([newValue compare:colour] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        selectedButton.backgroundColor = [backgroundColours objectAtIndex:index];
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare `NSNumber*` objects using the `<` or `>` operators: it compares pointers, giving you arbitrary results. Use the `compare:` method instead:

```
if ([newValue compare:[colorRange objectAtIndex:0]] == NSOrderedAscending) ...
```

- `NSOrderedAscending` means that the receiver is less than the argument
- `NSOrderedDescending` means that the receiver is greater than the argument
- `NSOrderedSame` means that the receiver is equal to the argument

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else said you cannot compare pointers like that, just variables.
You could use

```
if ([newValue floatValue]<[[color objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]
```